# Yield mutable.seq from mutable.traversable type in Scala

Tags: scala, collections, yield, mutable, seq

I have a variable `underlying` of type `Option[mutable.Traversable[Field]]`

All I wanted todo in my class was provide a method to return this as Sequence in the following way:

```
def toSeq: scala.collection.mutable.Seq[Field] = {
  for {
    f <- underlying.get
  } yield f
}
```

This fails as it complains that `mutable.traversable` does not conform to `mutable.seq`. All it is doing is yielding something of type Field - in my mind this should work?

A possible solution to this is:

```
def toSeq: Seq[Field] = {
  underlying match {
    case Some(x) => x.toSeq
    case None =>
  }
}
```

Although I have no idea what is actually happening when x.toSeq is called and I imagine there is more memory being used here that actually required to accomplish this.

An explanation or suggestion would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I am confused why you say that "I imagine there is more memory being used here than actually required to accomplish".  Scala will not copy your `Field` values when doing `x.toSeq`, it is simply going to create an new `Seq` which will have pointers to the same `Field` values that `underlying` is pointing to.  Since this new structure is exactly what you want there is no avoiding the additional memory associated with the extra pointers (but the amount of additional memory should be small).  For a more in-depth discussion see the wiki on [persistent data structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure#Examples_of_persistent_data_structures).

Regarding your possible solution, it could be slightly modified to get the result you're expecting:

```
def toSeq : Seq[Field] = 
  underlying
    .map(_.toSeq)
    .getOrElse(Seq.empty[Field])
```

This solution will return an empty `Seq` if `underlying` is a `None` which is safer than your original attempt which uses `get`.  I say it's "safer" because `get` throws a `NoSuchElementException` if the Option is a `None` whereas my `toSeq` can never fail to return a valid value.

**Functional Approach**

As a side note: when I  first started programming in scala I would write many functions of the form:

```
def formatSeq(seq : Seq[String]) : Seq[String] = 
  seq map (_.toUpperCase)
```

This is less functional because you are expecting a particular collection type, e.g. `formatSeq` won't work on a `Future`.

I have found that a better approach is to write:

```
def formatStr(str : String) = str.toUpperCase
```

Or my preferred coding style:

```
val formatStr = (_ : String).toUpperCase
```

Then the user of your function can apply `formatStr` in any fashion they want and you don't have to worry about all of the collection casting:

```
val fut : Future[String] = ???
val formatFut = fut map formatStr

val opt : Option[String] = ???
val formatOpt = opt map formatStr
```

Comment: very useful. my concern here was purely memory usage and performance

Comment: @ChrisBeck The performance for both memory and time will be O(n), but as I said in the response the memory usage should be pretty small since it's only pointers.